# ¿Como obtener valores numericos grandes correctamente de excel xlsx con php?

Tags: php, phpexcel

En mi app web importo datos a través de archivos .xlsx. El problema lo encuentro cuando importo un campo de tipo numerico (en el excel) que contiene un numero de 17 digitos.
Si el número es 86909203669377500, php me devuelve el valor 86909203669377504. En otros casos llega a devolverme el numero restandole 4 o incluso 8, según por donde quiera la libreria PHPExcel.
Para cargar los ficheros utilizo el siguiente código:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$valor = $sheet->getCell($columna . $index);
```

¿Alguien ha tenido un problema parecido?
Trabajo con la versión php 5.3.5

Comment: php 5.3.5 ??? por que tan abajo, nunca actualizaron versiones ???

Comment: Yo soy un mandado como aquel que dice.... Hay esta versión en mi trabajo y dicen que no se puede actualizar por que dejarian de funcionar otras cosas....

Comment: [5.3.5
Released: 2012](https://prototype.php.net/versions/5.3.5/)... OMG XD En ese tiempo nisiquiera programaba, asi que suerte !!!! Quizás puedas probar otra libreria rapidamente para ver si se corrige el error.

Comment: He estado buscando librerias pero claro.... con esta versión de php es dificil

Comment: mmm si ese campo lo conviertes en string te funcionara? O intenta crear un documento excel con solo ese numero e importarlo para ver como funciona ahi

Comment: @Nerpianicolindo intenta cambiando la directiva [`precision`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.precision), por ejemplo, `ini_set('precision', '20');`

Comment: @JuanRivera Si, así funciona sin problema. La cosa era encontrar otra solución para que los usuarios no estén cambiando cosas de los documentos y no la lien más.

Comment: @Marcos Si, eso también lo intenté pero no me dio resultado. Gracias de todas formas